# I create 5 Items in opc group,but I can't get them in DataChange method

Tags: c#, opc

I create a OpcGroup with OpcAutomation,then I add 5 items .But I can't get them in DataChange method.The prompt is IndexOutofRange exception.My problem is how to get the five variables in this method.Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OPCAutomation;
using System.Threading;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        #region 私有变量
        /// <summary>
        /// OPCServer Object
        /// </summary>
        OPCServer KepServer;
        /// <summary>
        /// OPCGroups Object
        /// </summary>
        OPCGroups KepGroups;
        /// <summary>
        /// OPCGroup Object
        /// </summary>
        OPCGroup KepGroup;
        /// <summary>
        /// OPCItems Object
        /// </summary>
        OPCItems KepItems;
        /// <summary>
        /// OPCItem Object
        /// </summary>
        OPCItem[] KepItem=new OPCItem[5];
        /// <summary>
        /// 主机IP
        /// </summary>
        string strHostIP = "";
        /// <summary>
        /// 主机名称
        /// </summary>
        string strHostName = "";
        /// <summary>
        /// 连接状态
        /// </summary>
        bool opc_connected = false;
        /// <summary>
        /// 客户端句柄
        /// </summary>
        int itmHandleClient = 0;
        /// <summary>
        /// 服务端句柄
        /// </summary>
        int itmHandleServer = 0;
        #endregion

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            KepServer = new OPCServer();
            try
            {
                KepServer.Connect("KEPware.KEPServerEx.V4", "127.0.0.1");
                KepGroup = KepServer.OPCGroups.Add("Loading");
                SetGroupProperty();
                KepItems = KepGroup.OPCItems;

                itmHandleClient = 1234;
                KepItem[0] = KepItems.AddItem("Channel_0_User_Defined.Sine.Sine1", itmHandleClient);
                itmHandleClient++;
                KepItem[1] = KepItems.AddItem("Channel_0_User_Defined.Sine.Sine2", itmHandleClient);
                itmHandleClient++;
                KepItem[2] = KepItems.AddItem("Channel_0_User_Defined.Sine.Sine3", itmHandleClient);
                itmHandleClient++;
                KepItem[3] = KepItems.AddItem("Channel_0_User_Defined.Sine.Sine4", itmHandleClient);
                itmHandleClient++;
                KepItem[4] = KepItems.AddItem("Channel_0_User_Defined.Sine.Sine5", itmHandleClient);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                KepGroup.DataChange += new DIOPCGroupEvent_DataChangeEventHandler(KepGroup_DataChange);
                //itmHandleServer = KepItem.ServerHandle;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
        private void SetGroupProperty()
        {
            KepServer.OPCGroups.DefaultGroupIsActive = true;
            KepServer.OPCGroups.DefaultGroupDeadband = 0;
            KepGroup.UpdateRate = 5000;
            KepGroup.IsActive = true;
            KepGroup.IsSubscribed = true;
        }

        private void KepGroup_DataChange(int TransactionID, int NumItems, ref Array ClientHandles, ref Array ItemValues, ref Array Qualities, ref Array TimeStamps)
        {
            label1.Text = ItemValues.GetValue(1).ToString();
            label2.Text = ItemValues.GetValue(2).ToString();
            label3.Text = ItemValues.GetValue(3).ToString();
            label4.Text = ItemValues.GetValue(4).ToString();
            label5.Text = ItemValues.GetValue(5).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqR3t.png)

Comment: Start with index 0 instead of 1?

Comment: @bub you are right this is an error. But the problem that this event may pass an Array which has variable number of items between 1-5. That is the reason the op may get the error at the 3rd item (because the array length was only 3)

Answer (score 0):

My guess that the DataChange event is fired *only for changed* tags (this event designed this way in the opc specification). So it may contain only one tag, or two etc.

So you need to check NumItems (this the number of the changed tags), and iterate *both* the ClientHandles and Itemvalues.